# Running out of RAM while gathering training data for Python Machine Learning Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, out-of-memory, training-data

I am working on a big personal project implementing a 3D CNN Model. The problem is that I run out of RAM while I gather the training data (the dataset is a collection of around 1000 small videos with a resolution of 480p).

What I currently do, is that I parse all videos from a folder, get every third of the frames, and normalize it before adding that frame to a list. I will leave the code here:

```
@dataclass
class ControllerClass:
    __ann_model: VectorModelANN
    __3d_cnn_model: Model3DCNN
    __ann_data: TrainerANNData
    __3d_cnn_data: Trainer3DCNNData


    @benchmark
    def gather_training_data(self, trainer_enum: TrainerEnum) -> Union[list, list]:
        x_training_data = []
        y_training_data = []
        counter_files = 1

        if trainer_enum.value == TrainerEnum.CNN_3D.value:
            trainer = TrainingDataGenerator3DCNN(
                vid='',
                cnn_3d_width=self.__3d_cnn_data.width_3d_cnn,
                cnn_3d_height=self.__3d_cnn_data.height_3d_cnn,
            )
        elif ...  # Not important code checker for this question

        for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()  + "/training data"):         
            print(f"INFO:GATHER_DATA_{trainer_enum.value}: Processing file {counter_files} with the name {filename}")
            counter_files+=1

            trainer.update_new_vid(filename)

            x_train_slice = trainer.generate_data()

            x_training_data.append(
                x_train_slice
            )
            y_training_data.append(
                transfor_file_name_into_int(filename)
            )
            print(f"INFO:GATHER_DATA: {sys.getsizeof(x_training_data)}")
        return x_training_data, y_training_data
```

In the current case I am using the TrainerDataGenerator3DCNN that looks something like this:

```
class TrainingDataGenerator3DCNN:
    def __init__(
        self, 
        vid,
        cnn_3d_width,
        cnn_3d_height,
    ) -> None:
        self.__vid = vid
        self.__3d_cnn_width = cnn_3d_width
        self.__3d_cnn_height = cnn_3d_height


    def normalize(self, img: Any) -> Any:
        img = cv2.resize(img, (self.__3d_cnn_width, self.__3d_cnn_height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (1,1), 0)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        
        img = img / 255

        return img


    def generate_data(self) -> list:
        final_3d_data = []

        if type(self.__vid) is str:
            self.__vid = cv2.VideoCapture("./training data/" + self.__vid)
        else:
            self.__vid = cv2.VideoCapture(self.__vid)

        count_frame = 0
        while self.__vid.isOpened():
            success, image = self.__vid.read()

            if not success:
                break

            if count_frame % 120 == 0:
                image = self.normalize(image)
                final_3d_data.append(image)
                count_frame = 0
            else:
                count_frame += 1

        self.__vid.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        return final_3d_data


    def update_new_vid(self, filename: str) -> None:
        self.__vid = filename
```

And the constants that I use for resizing:

```
WIDTH_3D_CNN = 480
HEIGHT_3D_CNN = 360
```

When printing the size of the training list, it does not appear to be that big:

```
INFO:GATHER_DATA_CNN_3D: Processing file 56 with the name abs_51.mp4
INFO:GATHER_DATA: 568
INFO:GATHER_DATA_CNN_3D: Processing file 57 with the name abs_52.mp4
INFO:GATHER_DATA: 568
INFO:GATHER_DATA_CNN_3D: Processing file 58 with the name abs_53.mp4
INFO:GATHER_DATA: 568
INFO:GATHER_DATA_CNN_3D: Processing file 59 with the name abs_54.mp4
INFO:GATHER_DATA: 568
INFO:GATHER_DATA_CNN_3D: Processing file 60 with the name abs_55.mp4
INFO:GATHER_DATA: 568
INFO:GATHER_DATA_CNN_3D: Processing file 61 with the name abs_56.mp4
INFO:GATHER_DATA: 568
INFO:GATHER_DATA_CNN_3D: Processing file 62 with the name abs_57.mp4
INFO:GATHER_DATA: 568
```

I am thinking that it could be a memory leak but I have no idea where.

I got 32GB of RAM and never thought it won't be enough. Is there something that I am missing? Should I perhaps resize the videos to a lower quality (like 240p)?

Comment: `sys.getsizeof(x_training_data)` only gives you the size of the list. What exactly is in `final_3d_data`.. a list of numpy arrays? What are the sizes of those things involved?

Comment: I would suggest creating an free tier AWS account and scale up. Working with images on 32 gb of ram is pretty small in my opinion.

Comment: you decompress video data into RAM? please estimate the size of uncompressed video. -- don't waste your resources. decompress on demand. there's absolutely no point to keeping all that in RAM all at once. if anyone tells you differently, they *probably* want to *sell* you something. -- the only reason "on demand" loading isn't done more commonly is that the libraries suck and don't make this easier... and the practice makes little sense in all the toy examples everyone writes their ad-revenue-producing blog posts about.